# how to find value from an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I need a help to create a VBA/Macro or any one time formula to solve my problem.

I have some string in column and want to find last date from the string.

Although I have solve it by applying formula but I have to write 3 different formula in different place.   My data looks like this:

> **Auth**

```
 A2  [UR: 12/6-12/11 det]
 A3  [UR; 11/18-12/11 php]
 A4  [UR: 9/30-10/4 det;iop(m-f)10/26-11/28 php; 11/30-12/21 iop (m-f)]
 A5  [UR; 10/12-10/16 det;11/1-11/27 php; 11/28-12/9 iop (m-f)]
 A6  [UR: 11/11-11/21 rtc; 11/22-11/28 php]
 A7  [UR: 11/8-11/14 det(m-f); 11/15-11/29 rtc; 11/30-12/9 php]
```

I only want date that is last of the string

```
12/11
12/11
12/21
12/09
11/28
12/09
```

In my first step I have remove (m-f) my formula is

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(AE3,FIND("(",AE3,1)-2),AE3)
```

In my Second Step I have removed all alphabets.  by applying below formula.

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(AF3),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z",""),"(",""),")",""),"",""),"]",""))
```

In my 3rd step

```
RIGHT(AG3,5)
```

But still I have to perform some manual work because last date in not in form of MM/DD.

Comment: VBA would definitely be advantageous here.  Split the string on the `]` then find the position of the last `-` in each string.  Then take the next 5 characters after that.

Comment: Is that data all in one cell?  Do you need the dates to be returned to a single cell also or separate cells?

Comment: My data is in different rows and want my answer in same cell. or it would be next column.